# Select a cell value from GridView asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with users and I want to be able to select the first column of a row - which is with usernames. I know how to do it with the `autogenerateselectbutton` property, but it doesn't look well on my design. So instead, I want to make it without the Select button. Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView5" AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle="alt" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Width="750px"
                            CausesValidation="False" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView5_PageIndexChanging"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridView5_SelectedIndexChanged" autogenerateselectbutton="True" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Username" ReadOnly="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="Last name" />
                            </Columns>
                            <selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightCyan"
     forecolor="DarkBlue"
     font-bold="true"/>  </asp:GridView>
```

If I remove the `autogenerateselectbutton`, then clicking on a row does nothing.

Here is my c# code, which takes the value from this cell and stores it into a string and then i call the `setUser()` function with the cell value as a parameter.

```
protected void gridView5_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView5.SelectedRow;
    string user = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    setSelectedUser(user);
}
```

I think the problem is in the `aspx` file, where I create my `GridView`, but don't know how  to make the row selectable without the `autogenerateselectbutton` set to true.

Comment: Have you debugged the c# code and tried to find if the value of `string user` is null or not?

Comment: Yes, I did, and if I remove the `autogenerateselectbutton` then it is null, but then it is not possible to select a row.

Comment: Is any of the below answers working for you?

Comment: Not so far, but may be it is me who don't know how to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the RowCommand method  you can create a asp:ButtonField column and set the command name

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
        if (e.CommandName=="MyCommand")
        {    
             int row = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
             var cellText= gvOwner.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text.Trim();
        }
   }
```

Comment: **FYI**: he's using GridView.SelectedIndexChanged Event

Comment: If you want to select a row without button and only by clicking on the row here id the solution : [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15898/Select-a-row-in-a-grid-view-with-a-click-on-row)

Comment: @FettMo But how do I set this ButtonField to take the results from my database, which are the usernames. With BoundField I can use `DataField="username"` and then how do I call the `RowCommand` ?

Comment: You could set the dataKeys

string username = GridView1.DataKeys[row].Value.ToString(); // value of the datakey;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx for more info on datakeys

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the selected index value of a particular row in which the user do any operation.then you have to get the rowindex value
If you want to Get a Value From a Label Control then"

```
Label l=(Label)Gridviewname.rows[e.rowindex].Findcontrol("label name of which you want to get the data")
String s=l.Text;
setselecteduser(l);
```

if you want to get the value from TextFiled

```
TextField t=(TextField)GridviewName.rows[e.rowindex].FindControl("Textbox Id of which you    want to get the data")
String s=t.Text;
SetSelecteduser(t);
```

Comment: the "RowIndex" property will get the entire row which the user has selected.can you explain exactly what you need mate?

Comment: The selection is not working - e.g. when I mouse over the cell that I want to select and when I click it nothing happens. Otherwise the code for taking the RowIndex and then the cell is correct.

Comment: setautogenerateselectbutton true and then                         `Protected Gridviewname_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender,EventArgs e 
        " Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property"
        GridViewRow  row= Grid2_item.SelectedRow
        "change background color of the selected row as you need so that the color will not disturb the look"
        row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Orange //or any color`

Comment: I have done that already, please read my post carefully. I want to get rid of this `autogenerateselectbutton` because it adds one more column to my grid view called Select and this doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Then you have to manually add background color for the cells on that particular row when the user is clicked on the username so that the user knows which row was selected. and for other rows do the same but give a condition so that previous selected row background colour will comeback to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok but does your page postbacking after select ? do you check postback control with
if(!ispostback) because when the page is postbacking the gridview will also, it means the grv will be empty. How can u get data from empty grv  you have use postback control where your datasource and databind lines...

Comment: Yes, but I am not doing anything else for now. Just storing the value of this cell into the `setSelectedUser` function. The idea is that after a button a click I will still be able to use the selected user.

Answer (score 0):

Put a linkbutton with Select text, command name as "Select" and pass "User name" as command argument.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkStatus" CommandName="Select" 
                             CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>' Text='Select' />
```

Now fire RowCommand event:-
Get username from argument, no need to get it from grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GridviewDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebApp.GridviewDemo" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
    <title></title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div>  
            <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >  
                <Columns>  
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SNo" DataField="EmpID" />  
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Name" DataField="EmpName" />  
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Age" DataField="EmpAge"  />  
                </Columns>  
            </asp:GridView>  
        </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html> 

protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
    {  
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString());  
        if (age >= 25 && age < 30)  
        {  
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;  
        }  
        if (age == 30)  
        {  
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;  
        }  
    }  
}
```